# How to plot in time series with ggplot, geom_line, with line group by 'answer'

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, multivariate-time-series

I have plotted this time series [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Z9Iq_eJJXgHr6Rml0lDpuJpQOU9e9V4) that contains three variables: date, answer, and counts.

I would like to plot in time series where the lines representing categories of the answers.
I have tried this codes below, but result are not as expected: I did't get any line. Could anyone help?

```
     bird %>% ggplot(aes(date, counts)) + 
geom_line(aes(colour = answer), show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_dl(aes(label = answer), 
        method = "last.points",
        position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +
      labs(x = 'year', y = 'percent',
        title = "Attitude towards X",
        subtitle = "Do you agree or disagree?",
        caption = "Data: Data Center") + 
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + 
    theme_ipsum(grid = "Y", ticks = TRUE)
```

[image]

THEN, I changed the answer value into numbers, where 'agree' = 1, 'disagree' = 2, and 'not know' = 3, and ran the same code resulting in similar plot,below.

[image]

How to plot it with the answer categories represented in 3 different lines on the plot, and its name at the right edge of each line. Many thanks for your help.

So, after a while, I was able to see the line with this updated code:

```
 p <- ggplot(data=snow,
            aes(x=date, y=counts, group=answer, col=answer)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_dl(
    aes(label = answer), 
    method = "last.points",
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.5)) +
  labs(
    x = 'year',
    y = 'percent',
    title = "Attitude towards X",
    subtitle = "Do you agree or disagree?",
    caption = "Data: Data Center") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_ipsum(grid = "Y", ticks = TRUE)
```

[image]

But, I need to ADD the name to the three LINES and also the specific value (percentage) to the line based on the date points on the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

snow %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), answer = factor(answer)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(answer) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, counts, colour = answer)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = . %>% slice_tail(n = 1), aes(label = answer),
            color = "black", nudge_x = 15, size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(counts, "%")), nudge_y = 3) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  labs(
    x = 'year',
    y = 'percent',
    title = "Attitude towards X",
    subtitle = "Do you agree or disagree?",
    caption = "Data: Data Center") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_ipsum(grid = "Y", ticks = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Allan. Wow, that's what I am looking for. That's really great! Thank you so much. But, how could I change the label of the line from numbers (1, 2, 3) into text (Agree, Disagree, Not know)?